# How to navigate to a non-wordpress page in a wordpress install without getting a 404 error?

Tags: 404-error

I am trying to set up MAMP Pro to be able to import my live wordpress site to my localhost.  I'm having issues, and MAMP provides a test file to upload and you can navigate to it and it will tell you what configuration issues you may have on your live site:
[link to their walkthrough](https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/FAQ/Remote/How-do-I-test-my-remote-credentials/)

The problem is when I put the file there and try to navigate to it, I get a "No Results Found" page.  I believe this is because wordpress has some protections to keep people from navigating to non-active wordpress pages?  How can I navigate to this file?  Thank you!

I tried the solution found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16584/non-wordpress-pages-code-getting-404-error), but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/416253/edit) to include the contents of your local site's `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard htaccess file (below), any non-WP page will be displayed before the WP htaccess lines are executed. This is because the standard htaccess file checks for 'not a file' and 'not a directory' to redirect to the WP content.

Standard htaccess file below (see https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/)

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```